# Renaming files with spaces and dots in the filename

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm making a simple *bat file with drag/drop ability for replacing white spaces( ) and dots(.) for underscores(_).

I think this should work, but it doesn't:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%f IN (%*) DO (
set filename=%%~nj
set filename=!filename:.=_!
set filename=!filename: =_!
if not "!filename!"=="%%~nf" RENAME "%%f" "!filename!%%~xf"
)
```

Do you know what is going on?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please try to find a proper "title" for your question. Yours is merely a line-up of keywords (called "tags" on SO).

Comment: with plain `FOR` you cannot access other tokens than the defined at the beginning of the for definition

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &setlocal

FOR %%f IN (%*) DO (
set "oldname=%%~ff"
set "oldfname=%%~nf"
set "extension=%%~xf"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "filename=!oldfname:.=_!"
set "filename=!filename: =_!"
if not "!filename!"=="!oldfname!" RENAME "!oldname!" "!filename!!extension!"
endlocal
)
```

Put the assignment of `set` in double quotes to protect your code from ugly characters. Set `delayed expansion` later in the for loop to save exclamation marks and carets in file names.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop variable is `%%f` but in the first line, where you assign it to `filename` you use `%%j`.

Your code should look like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%f IN (%*) DO (

rem corrected-begin
set filename=%%~nf
rem corrected-end

set filename=!filename:.=_!
set filename=!filename: =_!
if not "!filename!"=="%%~nf" RENAME "%%f" "!filename!%%~xf"
)
```

Also, you might want to make sure you strip eventual quotes consistently. That is, the last line of your loop should read:

```
if not "!filename!"=="%%~nf" RENAME "%%~f" "!filename!%%~xf"
```

Then, you should not suppress the directory-part of the files being moved.

```
if not "!filename!"=="%%~nf" RENAME "%%~dpnxf" "!filename!%%~xf"
```

Before letting your code loose, you may want to replace that last line with something like:

```
if not "!filename!"=="%%~nf" ECHO RENAME "%%~f" "!filename!%%~xf" >> "%TEMP%\test.txt"
```

Then, after your drag n' drop operation inspect "%TEMP%\test.txt" to see if it contains the operations, and on the files, you expected.

For reference, here is the complete file after all changes:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%f IN (%*) DO (
    set filename=%%~nf
    set filename=!filename:.=_!
    set filename=!filename: =_!
    rem uncomment  for debugging.
    rem if not "!filename!"=="%%~nf" ECHO RENAME "%%~dpnxf" "!filename!%%~xf" >>     "%TEMP%\test.txt"
    rem comment for debugging.
    if not "!filename!"=="%%~nf" RENAME "%%~dpnxf" "!filename!%%~xf"
)
```

Comment: Christian: The rename command doesn't support a path in the target name.

Comment: @foxidrive: Thanks, missed that. (Thankfully it does in the source name ;-)

Comment: You're right thanks!

The only thing is that i had to replace "rename" by "ren", but finally works fine